# WPF/C# Binding custom object list data to a ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, listbox, listboxitems

I've ran into a bit of a wall with being able to bind data of my custom object list to a `ListBox` in WPF.

This is the custom object:

```
public class FileItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the list:

```
private List<FileItem> folder = new List<FileItem>();
public List<FileItem> Folder { get { return folder; } }
```

The list gets populated and maintained by a `FileSystemWatcher` as files get moved around, deleted, renamed, etc.  All the list does is keeps tracks of names and paths.

Here's what I have in the MainWindow code-behind file (it's hard coded for testing purposes for now):

```
FolderWatcher folder1 = new FolderWatcher();
folder1.Run(@"E:\MyApp\test", "*.txt");

listboxFolder1.ItemsSource = folder1.Folder;
```

Here's my XAML portion:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listboxFolder1" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

Unfortunately, the only thing that gets displayed is `MyApp.FileItem` for every entry.  How do I display the specific property such as name?

Comment: So whats the problem? The binding isn't bound? Listbox displays wrong text? an error?

Comment: @Sayse Edited.  Sorry, I should have mentioned what exactly happens.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You will need to define the ItemTemplate for your ListBox

```
    <ListBox x:Name="listboxFolder1" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding}">
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 20):

The easiest way is to override [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx) on your `FileItem`, (The listbox uses this to populate each entry)

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.  I liked XAML version better, but this one did the job as well and like you said -- it's simple.  I just wanted to keep ToString() open for other things that may require return of path name or a combination of.

Comment: The difference is this will work when showing multiple list boxes :) no worries

Answer (score 10):

Each item in the list that ListBox shows automatically calls the `ToString` method to display it, and since you didn't override it, it displays the name of the type.

So, there are two things you can do here.

1. Override the `ToString` method like Sayse suggested.
2. Use [DataTemplate](http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html) and bind each of your properties seperatly

In your resource add the template with a key

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="fileItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

and give it as your listbox ItemTemplate

```
<ListBox x:Name="listboxFolder1" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource fileItemTemplate}">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, that guy knows how to explain things clearly.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone comes across this now via search, I just encountered pretty much the same issue in a C# UWP app.

While the XAML bits in Nitin's answer above were necessary, they didn't fix the issue alone -- I also had to change my equivalent of `Folder` to be an `ObservableCollection`, rather than a `List`, to get the ListBox to show the property I needed.