# Set each item in WPF ListBox differently

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am quite new with WPF & XAML. I am sorry for any beginners/stupid/contradictor questions since everything is mixed in my head right now. It seems that things are quite different than working with WinForms, so I am trying to do this WPF way.

In my app I want to use ListBox.

I have done what is required for most simple task:
- Connected ItemsSource property to my instance of IEnumerable (List in my case).
- In XAML I have ItemTemplate, so far nothing fancy:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ValueA}" />
<Label Content="{Binding ValueB}" />
```

This work ok, now I want to hide/show one of the labels if member of IEnumerable fulfil some condition. For this purpose I can use Visibility property of Label.

Example:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ValueB}" Visibility={Binding IsValueBVisible} />
```

But, how to run code behind for each member of IEnumerable and give information for property IsValueBVisible even if original member doesn't have it?

First solution that cross my mind is having some kind of wrapper around original IEnumerable object, but with properties such as **IsValueBVisible** included.

```
class MyItemsSource : IEnumerable<IMyItem>, IMyItem
{
    private OtherType _source;

    public List<OtherType>: SourceList { get; set; }

    public bool IsValueBVisible
    {
        get
        {
            // now we can use _source and decide on return value
        }
    }

    public MyItem this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            // Get original instance at index, do
            // comparisons, calculations etc.
            // return my value on which XAML can bind.
            _source = SourceList[index];

            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a sketch code,

It probably complicate things a lot, and is there maybe some other cleaner way? Trying to learn as much possible last days, but lost. Maybe it will be easier in couple of days.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Look here how to bind custom objects to a ListBox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692738/wpf-c-binding-custom-object-list-data-to-a-listbox this should solve your problems.

Comment: I don't see a point in `MyItemSource`. It can be a simple `ObservableCollection<SomeType>` property in ViewModel where `SomeType` has `IsVisible` (`bool` property, you shouldn't use `Visibility` type in ViewModel).... and now I noticed the lack of `MVVM` tag in the question, sorry.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't used ObservableCollection before, I will read about it now. Original members (models) of list don't have properties such as IsVisible, Visibility etc. but it's decided "outside", something like: if (ItemAtIndex is IHasBValue) && (ItemAtIndex.Value > 100)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a wrapper for your items:

```
public class MyItemWrapper
{
   public MyItemWrapper(MyItem item)
   {
     Info=item;
     IsVisible = true; 
   }
   public MyItem Info {get; set;}
   public bool IsVisible {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can use a list of `MyItemWrapper` instead of a list of `MyItem`:

```
List<MyItemWrapper> lstWrapperItems =  ... // create an instance of MyItemWrapper for each object of type MyItem
```

Now you can assign this newly created list to `ListBox.ItemsSource`, and then in the `Bindings` you can do the following:

`<Label Content="{Binding Info}" Visibility={Binding IsVisible} />`

Notice now that you don't need to use "InfoA" or "IsVisibleA", you only have to specify the name of the property in the wrapper class.

Comment: Thank you, can you only tell me if there is way to do wrapping "in-fly" without creating new instances? (sorry if beginner question)

Comment: @Bojan : I have updated the answer, by adding a constructor to the wrapper class. So you can simply use `wrapper = new MyItemWrapper(myItem)` .

Comment: You need to create an instance, in order to set the value of `IsVisible`. If you don't need `IsVisible`, then there is no need to use a wrapper...

Comment: Thanks again. I will try to provide more details: IsVisible (later maybe I will add IsImportantText etc.) is a property which is calculated (not stored) based on other Model's properties. So, I only need wrapper to provide visual informations to XAML (for Visibility property in my case), but this info differ from one list member to other list member. Ideal for me will be if there is something like this in XAML: `<label ...Visibility="{Binding GetVisibleForIndex()}">`.

Answer (score 0):

Learn the MVVM pattern, there is plenty info about it out there.

The goal is to wrap your `DataModel` in another class, the `ViewModel`, that implements the properties (in this case, at least `IsVisible`) to properly bind it to the `View`.

Comment: I am trying to use some remnants of MVVM in my example. IsVisible is called from MyItemsSource class. I have tried with implementing IEnumerable since it gives me index of requested item. Still new to WPF, maybe I mixed some things :)